# Multiple field distinct Aggregation in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some documents like this

```
{ name: 'John', likes: ['reading', 'cars'], dislikes: ['trees', 'cats']},
{ name: 'Ally', likes: ['drawing', 'cars'], dislikes: ['people', 'cats']},
{ name: 'Michelle', likes: [], dislikes: ['trees', 'cats']},
```

I'd like the aggregation to return all the unique values of each field like this

```
{ 
  name: ['John', 'Ally', 'Michelle'],
  likes: ['reading', 'cars', 'drawing'],
  dislikes: ['trees', 'cats', 'people']
}
```

Note, the `name` field is not an array, and the others are, and not all documents have included some of the arrays, like Michelle who has no `likes`. I've tried several $group methods with $unwind, which either don't include all the names properly (100 unique names, but only returning a 10) or mess up due to some documents not including a field such as 'likes'. Racking my brain all day on this, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

One [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) on **all** keys:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$likes", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$dislikes", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }  },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "name": { "$addToSet": "$name" },
    "likes": { "$addToSet": "$likes" },
    "dislikes": { "$addToSet": "$dislikes" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "name": { 
      "$filter": { 
       "input": "$name",
       "as": "el", 
       "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$el", null ] } 
      }
    },
    "likes": {
     "$filter": { 
       "input": "$likes",
       "as": "el", 
       "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$el", null ] } 
      }
    },
    "dislikes": {
     "$filter": { 
       "input": "$dislikes",
       "as": "el", 
       "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$el", null ] } 
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Use the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) if you really must to remove `null` values;